# When deploying next13 project with prisma get error

Tags: next.js, prisma

[image]

When I try to deploy my project in vercel I get this error I can not find any solution. I change some build commands to apply prisma but it's still not working

I tried to change command in package json I fully apply in the docs but it isn't working

Comment: In order to provide you with better help, you should add some code snippets and explain what you are trying to achieve and where exactly you experiencing the issues. Please add at least the code of the getListings and Home functions